# Filter is not working in node js that filter job by category ids

Tags: node.js, express, filter

I am working on node js with express and mongoDB. I have created two schema's one is `jobmodel` and another is `jobTypemodel` and everything is working with it routes, controllers and all but I have build a filter to filter jobs by category ids but it is not giving the desired output.

Here is the code:

jobsController.js

```
exports.showJobs = async (req, res, next) => {
    // enable search
    const keyword = req.query.keyword ? {
        tittle:{
            $regex: req.query.keyword,
            $options: 'i'
        }
    } : {}

    //filter job by category ids
    // it is not working currently
    let ids = [];
    const jobTypeCategory = await JobType.find({},{_id:1})
    jobTypeCategory.forEach(cat => {
        ids.push(cat._id);
    })

    let cat = req.query.cat;
    let categ = cat !== '' ? cat : ids;

     //enable pagination
     const pageSize = 5;
     const page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1;
    //  const count = await Job.find({...keyword}).estimatedDocumentCount();
     const count = await Job.find({ ...keyword, jobType:categ }).countDocuments();
    try {
        const jobs = await Job.find({ ...keyword, jobType:categ }).skip(pageSize * (page-1)).limit(pageSize);
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            jobs,
            page,
            pages: Math.ceil( count / pageSize),
            count,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

jobRoutes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { isAuthenticated, isAdmin  } = require('../middleware/auth');
const Job = require('../models/jobModel');
const { singleJob, updateJob, showJobs } = require('../controllers/jobsControllers');

//job  routes
// /api/job/creates
router.post('/job/create', isAuthenticated, isAdmin, async (req, res, next) =>{
    try {
        const job = await Job.create({
            tittle: req.body.tittle,
            location: req.body.location,
            batch: req.body.batch,
            location: req.body.location,
            desc: req.body.desc,
            company: req.body.company,
            jobType: req.body.jobType,
            user: req.user.id
        });
        res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            job
        })
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});

// /api/job/id
router.get('/job/:id', singleJob);
// /api/job/update/:job_id
router.put('/job/update/:job_id',isAuthenticated, updateJob);
// /api/jobs/show
router.get('/jobs/show', showJobs);

module.exports = router;
```

job type model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tittle:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'job tittle is required'],
        maxLength: 70,
    },
    batch:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'batch year  is required else write graduate'],
        maxLength: 70,
    },
    location:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'location is required'],
        maxLength: 70,
    },
    desc:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Discription is required'],
    },
    company:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required: [true, 'Company name is required'],

    },
    jobType: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "JobType",
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    }
}, {timestamps:true})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Job", jobSchema);
```

```
job type model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const jobTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobTypeName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'job category is required'],
        maxlength: 70,
    },

    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    },

}, {timestamps:true})

module.exports = mongoose.model("jobType", jobTypeSchema);
```

Postman giving result but not desired result because it is giving only one job post and when I'm running the api for all job so still it is showing only one job in all condition before that my search is working correctly.

note - if I remove  `jobType:categ` from job controller from here

```
const jobs = await Job.find({ ...keyword, jobType:categ }).skip(pageSize * (page-1)).limit(pageSize);
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            jobs,
            page,
            pages: Math.ceil( count / pageSize),
            count,
        })
```

then only it showing all job result.

I am developing an API to filter job by category but it is unable to filter whereas in cloud of MongoDB data is stored but unable to get it as demanded.

Answer (score 0):

If your ids/categ is an array, then your query should be

```js
   { ...keyword, jobType: { $in: categ } }
```